# Issue in LayoutInflater: No output is displayed, and the app crashes

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface, layout-inflater

In my application, I have created a folder and wrote text files into it. Now, I need to display them. Following is the Java code, where the main operation begins.

```
private class OpenFileEvent implements OnClickListener
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            LinearLayout openFileDialogView = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.open_file_dialog);

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final Dialog openFileDialog = new Dialog(Notes.this);
            openFileDialog.setTitle("Open File");
            openFileDialog.setContentView(R.layout.open_dialog);


            //First, list all the available Files
            File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Main Notes/Notes/");
            File file = new File(folder.getAbsolutePath());

            File[] fileNameList = file.listFiles();

            try
            {
            if(fileNameList != null && fileNameList.length>0)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<fileNameList.length;i++)
                {
                    //Get the sub views first
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                    View openThisFileView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.open_dialog_file, null);      
                    Button openThisFileButton = (Button)openThisFileView.findViewById(R.id.open_this_file_button);
                    Button appendThisFileButton = (Button)openThisFileView.findViewById(R.id.append_note_this_file);
                    TextView openThisFileNameTxt = (TextView)openThisFileView.findViewById(R.id.open_this_file_name);

                    //Set the Text
                    openThisFileNameTxt.setText(fileNameList[i].getName());

                    //Set the Listeners


                    //Add the View
                    openFileDialogView.addView(openThisFileView);

                }
            }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(VoiceNotes.this, "The Error is: "+e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            //Show the Dialog
            openFileDialog.show();




        }

    }
```

Here, the `try..catch` is required to run in device. Without it, the app simply crashes. Emulator do not need it. In real device, the error message is `The Error is: null`. No issues in emulator.

The above dialog is created with the help of another layout. Here it is.

**open_dialog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/open_file_dialog"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#ffffff">


</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see in the Java code, the space in `open_dialog.xml` is filled by another view, which represent the file name and 2 buttons. It is the one which get activated by Here it is.

**open_dialog_file.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/open_dialog_file_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/open_this_file_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/append_note_this_file"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/open_this_file_button"
        android:text="@string/append_note" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/open_this_file_button"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/open" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

So my question is, why this don't work in real device? Before I post this code I tested whether the folder this code is looking for is existed or not, and as I guessed, it is existing.

In real device, when I use the `try catch`, the dialog with only the title get displayed. But the dialog is empty. Apart from that, the only other output is the `Toast` message.

So what is the issue here?

Comment: @halfer: Thanks Halfer. Yes I reposted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not with IO. It is with layout inflating. In Emulator it did not come up because no data to be displayed, so no inflating. I found the issue is with `LayoutInflater` or something related to that, because I managed to get the list of folders and display it in a Toast without displaying in any external view.

Answer (score -1):

Did you put the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```